# ERROR - The instance of SQL Server you attempted to connect to does not support CTAIP

Tags: azure-synapse

I have created a new Azure SQL Data Warehouse database on a new logical server from the backup of a Azure SQL Data Warehouse database on a different logical server (using the Azure portal).  I created the LOGINs on the new MASTER database for the users that would connect to the new Azure SQL Data Warehouse database.  The users were restored to the new Azure SQL Data Warehouse database as expected per:

```
 SYS.DATABASE_PRINCIPALS
```

Now when I attempt to connect with those users, I receive an error:

```
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server : The instance of SQL Server you attempted to connect to does not support CTAIP..
```

We use sql-server authentication, running the following on both the original and new MASTER:

```
CREATE LOGIN 
 the_userID
with password = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
;
GO
```

and the following pattern on the original ADW database:

```
CREATE USER [the_userID] FROM LOGIN [the_userID]
;
GO
```

Is there any solution other than dropping and reCREATEing the users in the new ADW database?

Answer (score 4):

CTAIP error is a rather poorly worded error message indicating the login (in master) does not have a corresponding user in the DW.

In this case, you need to drop the existing user in the DW and re-create it for the login in master.

It doesn’t work automagically (yet) because we track the association using security identifiers (SID) not names and the new login in master has a new/unique SID. AAD logins and contained users (not currently supported in DW) don’t have this problem.

Comment: This looks a bit like a quote?  Consider making this as such and attributing its source, then mark as a self-answer.  Thanks for sharing.